# Haskell 99, Problems 1-10 (simple list processing)

Tags: beginner, haskell

I'm just learning Haskell and I wanted to know if I'm going in the right direction with my [solving of the Haskell 99 problems](https://wiki.haskell.org/H-99:_Ninety-Nine_Haskell_Problems).  The file of interest is [here](https://github.com/emmruld/learn-haskell/blob/master/H-99/OneToTen.hs) which I've also reproduced below.

```
module OneToTen where

{-- Problem 1: Find the last element of a list. --}
myLast :: [a] -> a
myLast [] = error "Empty list."
myLast [x] = x
myLast (x:xs) = myLast xs


{-- Problem 2: Find the last but one element of a list. --}
myButLast :: [a] -> a
myButLast [] = error "Empty list."
myButLast [x] = error "One element list."
myButLast [x,y] = x
myButLast (x:xs) = myButLast xs


{-- Problem 3: Find the Kth element of a list. The first element in the list
 -- is number 1 --}
elementAt :: [a] -> Int -> a
elementAt [] _ = error "Empty list."
elementAt (x:_) 1 = x
elementAt (_:xs) n = elementAt xs (n-1)


{-- Problem 4: Find the number of elements of a list. --}
myLength :: [a] -> Int
myLength xs = myLengthAux xs 0

myLengthAux :: [a] -> Int -> Int
myLengthAux [] acc = acc
myLengthAux (_:xs) acc = myLengthAux xs (acc+1)


{-- Problem 5: Reverse a list. --}
myReverse :: [a] -> [a]
myReverse xs = myReverseAux xs []

myReverseAux :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
myReverseAux [] acc = acc
myReverseAux (x:xs) acc = myReverseAux xs (x:acc)


{-- Problem 7: Flatten a nested list structure. --}
data NestedList a = Elem a | List [NestedList a]

flatten :: NestedList a -> [a]
flatten xs = flattenAux xs []

flattenAux :: NestedList a -> [a] -> [a]
flattenAux (List []) acc = acc
flattenAux (Elem x) acc = x:acc
flattenAux (List (x:xs)) acc = flattenAux (List xs) (acc ++ (flattenAux x []))


{-- Problem 8: Eliminate consecutive duplicated of list elements. --}
compress :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a]
compress [] = []
compress (x:xs) = compressAux xs x [x]

compressAux :: (Eq a) => [a] -> a -> [a] -> [a]
compressAux [] y acc = acc
compressAux (x:xs) y acc | x == y = compressAux xs y acc
                         | x /= y = compressAux xs x (acc ++ [x])


{-- Problem 9: Pack consecutive duplicates of list elements into sublists. If a
 -- list contains repeated elements they should be placed in separate sublists.
 --}
pack :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [[a]]
pack [] = error "Empty list."
pack (x:xs) = packAux xs x [x] []

packAux :: (Eq a) => [a] -> a -> [a] -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
packAux [] _ xs acc = acc ++ [xs]
packAux (x:xs) y ys acc | x == y = packAux xs y (y:ys) acc
                        | x /= y = packAux xs x [x] (acc ++ [ys])

{-- Problem 10: Run-length encoding of a list.  Use the result of problem P09
 -- to implement the so-called run0length encoding data compression method. --}
encode :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [(Int,a)]
encode [] = error "Empty list."
encode xs = map (\ys -> (length ys, head ys)) (pack xs)
```

I'm most curious if implementing all of these auxiliary methods is standard practice?  It's easier for me to think of a recursive problem using an accumulator, consequently, I write most of them this way.  Is this correct?  Should I be writing them differently?

Comment: myLast is the same as tail. and myButLast is last.tail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solutions 1 and 2 are fine.

#### Solution 3: Find the Kth element of a list

The error message for 3 is a bit misleading: you can also get the error if the requested index is beyond the end of the list.  Strictly speaking, it should be an error to request a non-positive index as well.

#### Solution 4: Find the number of elements of a list

You should not need a helper function.

```
myLength :: [a] -> Int
myLength [] = 0
myLength (x:xs) = 1 + myLength xs
```

However, as @Franky points out, using a helper function can make it tail-recursive.

#### Solution 5: Reverse a list

You *could* write it as `myReverse (x:xs) = (myReverse xs) ++ x`, but it is much more efficient the way you wrote it using a helper function.  The helper should be scoped using a `where` clause (or `let … in`, which does the same thing).  It is customary to name trivial helper functions using the `myReverse'` convention.

```
myReverse :: [a] -> [a]
myReverse xs = myReverse' xs []
  where
    myReverse' []     rev = rev
    myReverse' (x:xs) rev = myReverse' xs (x:rev)
```

#### Solution 7: Flatten a nested list structure.

No helper is necessary.

```
data NestedList a = Elem a | List [NestedList a]

flatten :: NestedList a -> [a]
flatten (Elem x)      = [x]
flatten (List [])     = []
flatten (List (x:xs)) = flatten x ++ flatten (List xs)
```

#### Solution 8: Eliminate consecutive duplicated list elements

Again, no helper or accumulator is necessary.  Furthermore, you should avoid `++`, as it works by inefficiently walking to the end of its LHS argument.

```
compress :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
compress []     = []
compress (x:[]) = [x]
compress (x:y:zs)
  | x == y      = compress (y:zs)
  | otherwise   = x : compress (y:zs)
```

#### Problem 9: Pack consecutive duplicates of list elements into sublists

I don't think that packing an empty list should be an error.  Rather it should just return an empty list.

My advice is similar to the above.  I think that a helper function is needed, but not in that way.

```
pack :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]]
pack [] = []
pack (x:xs) = pack' [x] xs
  where
    pack' run []  = [run]
    pack' run@(r:_) (x:xs)
      | x == r    = pack' (x:run) xs
      | otherwise = run : pack' [x] xs
```

#### Problem 10: Run-length encoding of a list

Again, I don't think that encoding an empty list should be an error.

The implementation would read more nicely, in my opinion, using a list comprehension and better naming.

```
encode :: Eq a => [a] -> [(Int, a)]
encode xs = [(length run, head run) | run <- pack xs]
```

---

In summary, accumulators are sometimes the right approach (as in `myReverse`), but often they are harmful.  Before using one, think hard about whether it is necessary and efficient.

Comment: Solution 4: The @emmruld helper function is tail recursive, yours not. Not that it matters unless strictness is added.